# Developer unlocked windows phone gets locked for no reason

Tags: windows-phone, unlock, locked

I have 2 windows phone devices on my account that I use for testing. But they get locked for no reason.. I have to unlock it almost everyday. It even happened twice in one day. I haven't figured out what is causing this...

Is anyone experiencing this same issue?

**** UPDATE MESSAGE ****

This is the latest bizzare update on this bug... I've pasted my post in Microsoft Forum below:

I'm experiencing a very strange bug that I don't know if it is on the Windows Phone SDK or in Visual Studio.

I have 2 WP 8.1 devices to test an app that I'm developing. This was the sequence of events that led to this lock down:

Suddenly one phone that I used the most started to ask, almost everyday, to develop unlock the device...
Then the other phone started to do the same. 
Now everytime I make a release version and run it targeting Device in Visual Studio, VS 2013 crashes... And the phone gets developer locked again.

Then I found a workaround that was to use the Application Deployment tool from the SDK only to test the release version. (Debug version it deployed without any problems on the device)

Today I forgot the manually deploy the XAP and clicked run in VS. VS crashed... Then I tried to deploy using the SDK tool it said that phone was locked... I unlocked it and clicked on the Deploy button again. Then the error: The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached appeared.

I've uninstalled the app from the Windows Phone device manually and tried again and the same error occured.

I tried the other test device and had to register it again and got the same error.

Now I can't deploy any release version and I don't know how to fix this issue.

Do you know how can I fix all this Visual Studio bugs?  I can't seem to find anyone else with the same problem as I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

No, i have three unlocked devices in my account but one wp8.1 and other two win10, if you can upgrade your wp8.1 devices to windows 10 do that using that [app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4) because windows has inbuilt feature to developer unlock device, so your device won't get locked again automatically.

if you don't want to upgrade to and need assistance go to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?locale=EN-US&supportregion=EN-US&ccfcode=US&pesid=14654&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&tenant=store&supporttopic_L1=31762110&ccsid=636134043097072797)
this link requires you to login with your outlook account or **may** require you to login with your windows developer account.

and **extra information** if don't have windows developer account and want to publish your app go to this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh51s0c) from your windows mobile device or directly search for "Dev Share" App in windows store.

Comment: if assistance link is not work go to this link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support and scroll down to contact us block to right side which have chat and email support for developers

Comment: I can't upgrade to win10 yet. I'm still converting the app that was in Silverlight to Universal.
thanks for the support link I'll try that and also Microsoft Forums.
The problem just escalated quiqly. see my update...

Comment: One thing you can do i think your error of maximum limit may resolve.

Comment: Remove your sd card from phone and insert it to a memory card and then if you have win 10 or8.1 in pc just girl view > option and new window will appear then go to view tab on it, then click on show hidden files and folder, and + don't forget to unchecked hide System recommend file& folder.

Comment: Then, goto you sd card from this pc or my computer then here is folder name wpsystem, now from here is up to you, just delete folder with your visual studio project package name, because when we uninstall any app some app left in memory, it may be counted in number of app deploy.

Comment: both phones don't have SD card.. only internal memory. I wasn't able to find that folder. do you know a workaround?

Comment: deleting cache folders seems a good idea. Do you know if VS also keeps a folder in the PC with deployment information?

Comment: in you pc go to C:\Users\yourusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2015(any version in your case)\Projects\yourapp\your app sub folder/

Comment: here you need to fully empty bin and obj folder

Comment: I haven't sd card on phone then do insert, and go to storage and set new app install to SD card then Debug again.

Comment: I don't know that if was this step that fixed the maximum number of developer applications error or if Microsoft did domething at their servers (I've opened a customer support request)
I did project clean lots of times but it seems that the build clean doesn't delete all files in those folders

Comment: because of your previous application installed on your phone memory so you cant delete application debugging files from phone , so finally you need to hard reset and next time debug apps in memory card, because later you can clean your sd card manually by  using SD card reader.

alternately you can go through this type of articles

Comment: http://4mobiles.net/windows-phone/tutorials-windows-phone/jailbreak-any-windows-phone-running-windows-88-1/